# How to customize logging for Google App Engine Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

Google App Engine Java uses java.util.logging to create logging messages. **I want to modify the log messages, that are displayed in Developers Console - Monitoring - Logs**. The idea is to add some additional output like username without putting it in each log message manually:

```
log.info("user action");
```

should result in an logging output like

```
user "testuser": user action
```

Therefore I created an own Formatter:

```
public class TestFormatter extends Formatter {
    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        // find out username..
        return "user " + username + ": " + record.getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Setting this as formatter for the ConsoleHandler in the logging.properties has not effekt:**
`java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = com.example.guestbook.TestFormatter`

When deploying it in on the local machine, and trying to add it programmatically like this:

```
Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
log.info("Handler[] size: " + handlers.length);
for(Handler h : handlers) {
    log.info(h.toString());
    h.setFormatter(new TestFormatter());
}
```

I get 2 handler, one `ConsoleHandler` and one `DevLogHandler`. **But setting the formatter results in the fact that no further logs are displayed.** On GAE instead I get 0 handler.

When trying to acces `Logger.getGlobal()` instead of `Logger.getLogger("")`, I get 0 Handler on the local instance and a *SecurityException: No permission to modify global* on GAE. This exception already arises when trying to get the list of Handlers.

**Now my question: Is there a way to modify the logs of developer console in such a way? If yes, how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I reply I got in the past from a Google ticket I opened for a similar question

> I would discourage tampering with the Loggers/Handlers used
>   internally by GAE.

Besides that, the Global Logger cannot be customized, you can try to it with a Logger with a custom name

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you add the link to the ticket? It is a quite important decision for my master theses;)

Comment: Sadly, it is a private ticket, is not accessibile outside the users from our company.

Comment: Ok, maybe there is an public source for that fact, or others solved the problem in any way.

Comment: I'll second what they said, although I don't think it's necessary to gain access to a private company's support portal to think about the reasoning. App Engine is [PaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) and so certain aspects of the environment are not customizable. The best way to log is using `log.info("user action");`. This is the normal way that all other users are doing logging, so I don't think there's any issue with it which would affect you. It shows up in the Developers Console as you'd like :)